# hp envy 15 installed windows 7 .no drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, hp-envy

I had windows 8 by default which i get rid of by installing windows 7.at the moment it didnt pick up any drivers,cant access usb,network to communicate with any external source to download install drivers,any idea welcomes

Comment: Do Micro SD slot works?

Comment: CD/DVD drive? What I would suggest is if you can get to Device Manager and get the Hardware Ids of the network card(s) and get them on here we can help identify the devices so you can put the right drivers on a disk. I'm very surprised your USBs aren't working, though... Can you get mouse/keyboard at all? PS/2 on the motherboard?